# The magic of the primes

Tags: mathematics, story, number-theory, magic-square, no-computers

A mathematician, a physicist, and an engineer found themselves caught in an ancient anecdote. Lacking a chemist to brew them an anecdote antidote, they fell to arguing over which of them was to be the butt of the joke ... when suddenly the physicist and the engineer disappeared! Between the spots where they'd been standing, a magician stood glaring at the mathematician.

"Long have those of thy profession sought to ridicule my kin," he said menacingly. "Wherefore then, now that thou art in my power, should I release thee? I shall trap thee in unamusing tales with thy fellow *scientists* for ever."

"As I see you are a magician," the mathematician began, "will a **magic square** enable me to avert your power?"

The magician scoffed. "What is thy field of expertise within that arid wasteland, Mathematics?"

"Number theory," the unperturbed<sup>1</sup> mathematician replied.

"Ha! Those fools who seek to discover pattern among the prime numbers! In that case, I challenge thee to find a $2015\times2015$ magic square all of whose entries are **prime**. If thou canst achieve this feat, I shall release thee unharmed; otherwise, thou art my slave for ever!"

---

**Can the mathematician succeed?** Give a proof either that such a magic square exists or that it cannot exist. Unlike the unfortunate mathematician, you don't actually need to construct it!

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Well, of *course* he was unperturbed. Perturbation theory is a branch of analysis, not number theory!</sub>

Comment: If the entries don't have to be unique...

Comment: I believe that unique elements is a prerequisite of a magic square.

Comment: (hence the ...)

Comment: I agree that it would be nice to mention, even if it's a safe assumption.

Comment: @Goinghamateur and Kingrames: I didn't think it was necessary to put any info that's already in the [magic-square] tag wiki. But I'll edit something in if you really want.

Comment: Can the magician grant me the proof or disproof of conjectures such as [Polignac's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture) and [Hardy-Littlewood's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture)?

Comment: @Roland ... or even Dickson's? But seriously, the mathematician will probably count himself lucky to get away alive (and it'll take him long enough!)

Comment: +1 for the metahumor, because I never metahumor I didn't like!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The mathematician's task is

> possible.

Proof:

> By the [Green-Tao Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem), there exists a sequence of $2015^2$ primes which form an arithmetic progression. This arithmetic progression can be arranged into an order 2015 magic square using the [usual method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_method). Namely, place the lowest prime in the middle of the top row. For each prime placed, the next prime will be placed one square northeast of it (wrapping around at the borders), unless this is already filled, in which case it will be placed one square south.

Comment: By "lowest prime", you must mean "lowest prime of the $2015^2$ chosen". My answer, which assumed the lowest is required, explains why this cannot be done.

Comment: @Roland The only problem your answer had was you assumed that you must use 2. But that's not necessarily the case.

Comment: @Anachor I understand that; just making sure his use of "lowest prime" isn't misunderstood.

Comment: This solution ends up being remarkably simple!

Comment: Well, a solution is possible, but he is still toast if he can not find (and write down) that solution. And given that [the lowest known 26 element AP is of 18 digits](http://primerecords.dk/aprecords.htm) I would say, he should stop trying.

Comment: @randal'thor Do you know of a solution that doesn't use the Green-Tao theorem? It's solid as a solution, but I'd like the puzzle to not require such high-powered machinery.

Comment: @xnor No, a result as cool as this needs to use high-powered machinery! Mathematical results don't come for free :-P I suspect this is actually equivalent to Green-Tao. Exercise for the reader: prove Green-Tao using the result of this post. :-)

Comment: And good job, Mike! I thought one of the maths heads like you or xnor or Julian Rosen would get this quickly. Had you seen the result before, or did you work it out on the spot?

Comment: @Anachor That is indeed the catch! But maybe it's the [engineer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9000/engineer-toast) and not the mathematician who's toast in the end?

Comment: Sorry Mike for this personal question and if you don't want to answer it is OK. Do you have a Ph.D You seems to me quite knowledgeable.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the mathematician must use all primes in ascending order, as I gathered from a quick *magic square* search:

> It cannot be done. The mathematician must place the number $2$ in a square. With 2014 other primes, all odd, its row and column must add up to an even number. All columns and rows without $2$ will add up to an odd number.

Comment: Your logic is correct, but your assumption is false. Where does it say in the OP that the first $2015^2$ primes must be used??

Comment: Ah, it appears the definition I'm reading is what Wikipedia calls a *normal* magic square. My search result said that integers $1$ to $n^2$ must be used. Since the magician told us to use primes, I interpreted it as the first to $n^2th$ primes. Apologies.

Comment: I did the exact same thing @Roland. I've never heard of a magic square and the cursory google result says the numbers in a n x n square must be the set [1,n^2]. The second result down explains that this is not necessarily the case though

Comment: Shorter version: there aren't $2015^2$ primes in the first $2015^2$ numbers.  ;)  Once they are using primes, clearly a normal magic square is right out.